# Immediately exit a Parallel.For loop in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

In C#, is it possible to immediately exit a Parallel.For loop that is in progress. The following code can take up to a full second to exit the loop after loopState.Stop() has been called.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

    Parallel.For(0, 50, (i, loopState) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "\tIteration:" + i);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            watch.Start();
            loopState.Stop();
            return;
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed since loopState.Stop(): {0}s", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output

```
Thread:10       Iteration:0
Thread:6        Iteration:12
Thread:11       Iteration:24
Thread:12       Iteration:36
Thread:13       Iteration:48
Thread:13       Iteration:49
Thread:12       Iteration:37
Time Elapsed since loopState.Stop(): 0.9999363s
```

Is there any way to do this faster?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this possible. Look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx) article that goes into detail about Parallel programming question. Here is an excerpt for you out of it:

> What if I don’t want to waste resources and want to stop all
>   computations immediately after I click Cancel? In this case, I have to
>   periodically check for the status of the cancellation token somewhere
>   within the method that performs the long-running operation. Since I
>   declared the cancellation token as a field, I can simply use it within
>   the method.

```
public double SumRootN(int root)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        result += Math.Exp(Math.Log(i) / root);
    }
    return result;
}
```

using the traditional `Stop` or `Break` does not cause the task to be canceled immediately, as you are experiencing. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx) article on MSDN,

> In this context, "break" means complete all iterations on all threads
>   that are prior to the current iteration on the current thread, and
>   then exit the loop. "Stop" means to stop all iterations as soon as
>   convenient.

So you can't force it to stop immediately using the traditional method. You will need to use a method like I mentioned at the beginning.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Unfortunately my performance heavy call is inside a third party library but I may be able to improve my performance a bit with this technique. Thanks!

Comment: Disregard that last comment. This actually made a huge difference in performance. Although I used loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration instead of tokenSource.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the running time of the loop body.  `loopState.Stop()` stops any new loop iterations from beginning, and waits for any that are currently running to complete.